# The App does not start due to D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Tags: android, shared-libraries, android-multidex

I'm building an application that has a shared library and two applications that share this library.
**As soon as the application starts the logcat shows D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM.** 
**If I debug the application it does not launch my MainActivity (LoginActivity)**. The application crashs after return from attachBaseContext(Context base) in the Application Class.

This is not a simple case of NPE, the problem is that the VM is Shutting down and the only debuggable part is the Global.attachBaseContext that runs OK and after that the Logcat message is shown.

**LOGCAT**

```
    I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    I/MultiDex: install
    I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
    I/MultiDex: install
    I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
--------- beginning of crash
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: br.com.cfb.dogwalktracker_dogwalker, PID: 17406
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
    java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4769)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4709)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

**GradeBuild shared library**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Gradebuild (from dog walker Application)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.cfb.dogwalktracker_dogwalker"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    })
    compile project(':DogWalkTrackerShared')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**GradeBuild (From user Application)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.cfb.dogwalktrackeruser"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile project(':DogWalkTrackerShared')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

**GLOBAL**

```
public class Global extends Application {

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

**Manifest (from dog walker Application)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="br.com.cfb.dogwalktracker_dogwalker">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name="br.com.cfb.dogwalktrackershared.Global"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name_dogwalker"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="label">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name_dogwalker">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".GrantPermissionActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name_dogwalker"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".NavigationDrawer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="br.com.cfb.dogwalktrackershared.IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Manifest (From user Application)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.cfb.dogwalkertrackeruser">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name="br.com.cfb.dogwalktrackershared.Global"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="br.com.cfb.dogwalktracker_dogwalker.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name_dogwalker">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="br.com.cfb.dogwalktracker_dogwalker.GrantPermissionActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name_dogwalker"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".NavigationDrawer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Manifest from Shared Library**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.cfb.dogwalktrackershared">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi  LunarWatcher, The Activity even starts. The application crash after MultiDex.install(this); in the Global. Thanks.

Comment: I see `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
    java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference ` in your stacktrace. Meaning NPE, meaning duplicate

Comment: @Carlos, this crash doesn't have anything to do with multi-dex. You can see that in logs: `VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.`. Since your target device is Lollipop or greater, no multi-dex patching required, and library's patching code won't be invoked. I've checked the source code for [ActivityThread#installContentProviders](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#5808) function, but couldn't find where String#equals is being invoked. Which API version your (crashing) device has?

Comment: @Alex, thank you for your time. I decided to restore a backup and it worked.